# $rank(f,a)=rank(f´(a))$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

I have been searching on the internet,books for the proof of following result:

> Let U be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and let
>
> $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable map.
>
> Given $a\in U$, the rank of $f$ in the point $a$ is the ranl of the linear map $f´(a):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$;
>
> $rank(f,a)=rank(f´(a))$

I found it on the material that I am studying without a proof.

My intuition does not seem to conform with the fact. I have tried to build a proof but I am not succeeding.

**Question:**

Can anyone provide the proof of this identity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to give some definitions.

Comment: @DavidJaramillo Please check my update. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: hmmmm then I I might be wrong but I think this is just a definition. You are defining the rank of a function as the rank of its derivative (which is well defined as the derivative is a linear map)

Comment: Use `^\prime` or `’` instead of an acute accent mark